# How can I load Globalize translation fixtures to test models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, fixtures, globalize

I'm using the `gobalize` gem 4.0.3 in Rails 4.1.12.

I have a `Post` model and I've run the `Post.create_translation_table!` migration supplied by `globalize` to set up a `post_translations` table.

Now I want to automatically load translations from my fixture files. Fixtures support [label references for associations](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/FixtureSet.html#class-ActiveRecord::FixtureSet-label-Stable-2C+Autogenerated+IDs) so I have this:

```
# spec/fixtures/posts.yml

my_first_post:
  author: dave

# spec/fixtures/post_translations.yml

my_first_post_translation:
  locale: en    
  title: My first post
  content: What a time to be alive!
  post: my_first_post

# spec/models/post_spec

require 'rails_helper'

RSpec.describe Post, type: :model do
  fixtures('post/translations', :posts, :authors)

  subject(:post) { posts(:my_first_post) }

  it "has an author" do
    expect(post.author).to eq(authors(:dave))
  end

  it "has a title" do
    binding.pry
    expect(post.title).to be_present
  end
end
```

But running RSpec throws the following error:

```
 Failure/Error: Unable to find matching line from backtrace
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
   SQLite3::SQLException: table post_translations has no column named post: INSERT INTO "post_translations" ("locale", "title", "content", "post", "created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('en', 'My first post', 'This is some compelling english content', 'my_first_post', '2015-08-21 10:23:27', '2015-08-21 10:23:27', 626768522)
```

A similar error occurs if I do the inverse (i.e. `post_translation: my_first_translation` in `posts.yml`)

How do I get the magic back?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Solution

1. Move `fixtures/post_translations.yml` to `fixtures/post/translations.yml`
2. The key for the association in `my_first_translation` is `globalized_model`

So you will end up with this:

```
<!-- language: yml -->
# spec/fixtures/posts.yml

my_first_post:
  author: dave

# spec/fixtures/post/translations.yml

my_first_post_translation:
  locale: en
  title: My first post
  content: What a time to be alive!
  globalized_model: my_first_post
```

## Explanation

1. The translation model is `Post::Translation`. The namespacing means that the location of the `Post::Translation` fixtures must follow the same nesting conventions as a model in `app/models`.
2. The association name on `Post::Translation` (and any `globalize` translation model) is `globalized_model`. `ActiveRecord::FixtureSet` [uses the association name to recognise the fixture key as an association](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/345e71db6713ec98d9087c0067d12c3d316a967d/activerecord/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb#L656).

Comment: Dave, thank you very much for your help on this issue !!